# Manually installing packages in thin read-only distributions

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, dpkg

I am trying to install our product in a [NoTouchOS - a Raspberry Pi thin client OS](https://www.stratodesk.com/).

Given the fact it is a thin client, many libraries do not come out-of-the-box, such as `apt`, `sudo`...

I am trying to manually install apt (`Raspberry PI OS` is `debian` based), by manually downloading the `.deb` package and running `dpkg -i` (`dpkg` is present there), but I get

`unable to clean up mess surrounding './usr/bin/apt' before installing another version: Read-only file system`

As a matter of fact, I get the same error (on `./usr/bin/cvtsudoers`) when trying to install `sudo` package, in the same manner.

[image]

How should this be tackled ?
Posts I could find on the topic mention mounting. How do I know if this is a mounting issue ?

Comment: Read the error, the root filesystem is likely mounted as readonly

Comment: @NicolasFormichella: problem is a unix-familiar fellow (you) reading the error concludes things someone not familiar does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NoTouch OS is not based on Raspberry Pi OS or any other Linux distribution](https://kb.stratodesk.com/what-linux-distribution-is-used-for-notouch-os), so even if it has `dpkg`, installing packages from some other distribution is unlikely to end well.

Anyway, NoTouch OS is [designed to have an immutable base](https://kb.stratodesk.com/installing_3rd_party_apps#General-considerations); that’s why you can’t write to `/usr/bin`:

> NoTouch images are immutable and can not be modified after build, not even after installation.

Since NoTouch OS is designed as a VDI system, the general idea is to provide access to applications on a remote system, not to applications inside the NoTouch OS setup. It seems you *can* ship applications on NoTouch OS if you really want to, but only [in `/config` or `/tmp`](https://kb.stratodesk.com/installing_3rd_party_apps#Storing-your-application) (in the latter case, downloading the application at startup). But [Stratodesk would really prefer if you contracted them to do it for you](https://kb.stratodesk.com/installing_3rd_party_apps#Support-limitations) (unsurprisingly).

Getting down to brass tacks, since your applications seems to require a number of packages other than its own, I suspect your best bet might be to `debootstrap` a chroot inside `/config`, or to manually copy all the files you need for your application inside `/config`, without relying on packages at all.

Comment: There are [no connections](https://kb.stratodesk.com/what-linux-distribution-is-used-for-notouch-os) at all between this and RpiOS. This is a ground-up made distro

Comment: Highly appreciated comments/guidance.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella: I saw that docs page earlier, the reason I coupled NoTouch OS with Raspberry Pi and then Debian is that if you google for "NoTouch OS" you see the piece of information I added in the first line link on my post. I was happy with the docs statement, but then the google result title left me confused.

Comment: debootstrap is also missing there. When you say "or manually copy all files you need" you mean the binaries (packages extracted contents) ?

Comment: “A Raspberry Pi thin client OS” does not imply that there’s any connection with “Raspberry Pi OS”; all it says is that the OS is available for the Raspberry Pi. “or manually copy all the files you need” means exactly that — I imagine your program needs more than binaries, you need to copy all the files that your application needs.